# How will Comsol use the expression "0 10^range(2, 0.1, 7.5)"?

Tags: range, expression, mathematical-expressions, comsol

I am facing an issue with the `range` function. How will the following expression be used?

[image: settings of time-dependent study step]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of the `range` function is explained in section ["Entering Ranges and Vector-Valued Expressions"](https://doc.comsol.com/5.6/docserver/#!/com.comsol.help.comsol/comsol_ref_definitions.17.036.html) of the Comsol Reference Manual. It can only be used for input fields that expect multiple values, such as the output times of the time-dependent solver in the example from the question.

In this case, it creates an array with values 0, 10<sup>2</sup>, 10<sup>2.1</sup>,
… 10<sup>7.4</sup>, 10<sup>7.5</sup>, the default unit being seconds. You can see the effect of the expression by running the study and noting that the resulting data set contains solutions for times 0 s, 100 s, 125.89 s, … 2.5119e7 s, 3.162e7 s, where those numbers correspond to the given powers of 10.